# How to deploy to Google Cloud Platform from runnable image by maven?

Tags: image, maven, docker, web-deployment, google-cloud-platform

How to deploy to Google Cloud Platform from runnable image by maven?

I use https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven to generate runnable image and it can work localhost. And I want to mvn deploy to GCP and auto run.

How can I do that?
Thanks.
Can I do this just by maven? or Should I write a script by GCP command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google App Engine Flexible Environment. As stated on this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart):

> Custom runtimes let you build apps that run in an environment defined by a Dockerfile. By using a Dockerfile, you can use languages and packages that are not part of the Google Cloud Platform. Although you create a custom runtime, you are still able to use all the same resources and tooling to develop and manage your apps in the custom environment, that are use in the App Engine flexible environment.

Comment: Yes, you can use maven. Just install the [App Engine Plugin](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-maven) on Apache Maven and you can deploy using 'mvn appengine:deploy'